# Surmountability of the technical risks to launching EM-1 on commercial rockets?

Tags: nasa, falcon-heavy, orion-spacecraft, delta-iv-heavy

NASA administrator Bridenstine announced that commercial rockets (e.g., Delta Heavy and Falcon Heavy) would be considered as ways to launch EM-1 by July, 2020.

Such a move would reportedly require a mission architecture where the Orion & service module is launched separately from the departure stage. Four new pieces of development work would need to be done, tested and integrated for that to happen:

1. Adapting the service module to one launch vehicle, and associated software changes.
2. Adapting the departure stage to a second launch vehicle, with some sort of ejectable fairing, and associated software changes.
3. On-orbit rendezvous of the two un-manned vehicles and placement for mating to occur.
4. On-orbit mating of the service module and departure stage with a mechanism through which the departure stage can push Orion on its way.

My question is: With the vehicles and engineering resources likely be available, and reuse of existing solutions where available, **how surmountable are the technical risks of these four things in the time frame being discussed?**

This question is more about engineering than production and logistics – though information on how feasible it is to produce and launch two Delta Heavy or Falcon Heavy vehicles back-to-back might constrain what solutions are even worth thinking about.

Comment: This post addresses somewhat the ability of heavy lift boosters to launch Orion, but not from the perspective of EM-1 (un-manned) and rapidly producing a multi-launch architecture using Delta, Falcon, or both:  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5190/what-missions-could-be-done-with-orion-on-falcon-heavy